# Adding fixtures with its associations in Cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

after I did some research, I didn't find any proper answer to this question.

I'm starting writing tests for my CakePHP (3.x) app and I was wondering how can we add fixtures and their associations?. In other words, how can we link a fixture to another without writing the Primary and foreign keys directly inside the fixture.

i.e

I have a Users table and a UserProfiles table.
User hasOne UserProfile through user_id column. Here's my user fixture.

```
namespace App\Test\Fixture;

use Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture;

class UsersFixture extends TestFixture
{

    public $import = ['table' => 'users'];
    public $records = [

        [
            'username' => 'mark@mail.com',
            'primary_role' => 1
            'is_active' => 1,
        ]
    ];

}
```

And here's my UserProfile fixture

```
namespace App\Test\Fixture;

use Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture;

class UserProfilesFixture extends TestFixture
{

    public $import = ['table' => 'user_profiles'];
    public $records = [

        [
            'first_name' => 'Mark',
            'last_name' => 'Yellowknife',
        ]
    ];

}
```

How do I link both record together? Aka, how can I tell the user profile record to add its user_id to be linked to the user record?

Must be a way to do this with Fixtures without writing the keys manually.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define this in the fixtures. The only other way would be to issue update queries at runtime to set the foreign keys, but that's anything but a good idea.

Other than that there isn't really a way to do this, I mean, how would any code know which records needs to be associated with each other without you explicitly defining it?

So, you'll have to at least define the foreign key, and depending on how primary keys are being generated (auto incrementing integers, UUIDs, etc), you might have to define them too.